# Dynamically create and print h1 tags through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to be able to create a function in JavaScript where all I need to do is type h1("hello") and it will print hello.

I want to avoid this method:

```
function h1(text) {
    document.write('<h1>'+text+'</h1>');
}
```

This is what I have:

```
function h1(text) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    document.appendChild(div);
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    div.appendChild(h1);
    h1.createTextNode(text);
}
```

Comment: So, what does/doesn't work with what you have?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<script>
function myFunction(text) {
    var h = document.createElement("H1");
    var t = document.createTextNode(text);
    h.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(h);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the `div`, and you need to append to `document.body`, not `document`. Also, elements don't have a `createTextNode`, that's a method on `document`:

```
function h1(text) {
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    document.body.appendChild(h1);
}
```

Live example:

```js
function h1(text) {
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    document.body.appendChild(h1);
}
var counter = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  ++counter;
  h1("Hi #" + counter);
  if (counter == 5) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 500);
```

More to explore:

- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [DOM HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org)
- [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) spec (which is about a lot more than HTML)

Answer (score 1):

The better way would be to Import [ElementsJS](https://github.com/divyamshu/Elements-JS) and just reference each element in it.

```js
// Create H1 Without Class
var root = document.getElementById("root");
create_element('h1',null, root, "This is a H1 Text");


// Create H1 With Class
var root = document.getElementById("root");
create_element('h1',{'class':'h1css'}, root, "This is a H1 Text");
```

```css
.h1css {
  background-color : grey;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://elementsjs.blob.core.windows.net/public/create-elements.js"></script>
<body id="root"></body>
```