# How can I write a script which help me to add H1 tag in between Div tag in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on Squarespace website. I am trying to add H1 tag automatically via script in Div tag. Below is the div tag in which I have text. I want to asign H1 tag to this text via script or any other method.

```
<div class="image-slide-title">
St. Stephens
</div>
```

The squarespace doesn't allow me to add H1 tag manually via coding. I can't use CSS code and when I use CSS code it changes the class and mess the area.

[image]

Comment: can u plz share your entire code?

Comment: `I use CSS code it changes the class and mess the area` You cannot add `<style>.image-slide-title { font-size : xx-large; font-weight:bold }</style>` somewhere after the Squarespace stylesheet?

Comment: you can see code here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929786/dynamically-create-and-print-h1-tags-through-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could try to insert it in the DOM, like this :

```
const myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('image-slide-title')[0];

let title = document.createElement('h1');
title.innerHTML = 'whatever you would like it to be';

myDiv.appendChild(title);
```

Comment: Is myDiv a class or it’s a tag script language?

Comment: @PritiRathod `myDiv` is a Javascript object that contains your HTML div : you retrieve it from the DOM using `document.getElementsByClassName`, then create a DOM H1 object (named title) and append it to your `myDiv`

Comment: I'd use querySelector

Comment: Squarespace just give access to inject code either in header or footer. Can I inject this code in either of it?

Comment: @PritiRathod if I understand well, you mean to inject Javascript code inside `<script>` tags, both in the header/footer ? In this case, yes it will work, for both of these. Also don't forget to mark the answer as valid if it worked for you ;-)

Comment: Hi, the code works but how can I display the value St. Stephens? How can I fetch this data and displaying instead of 'whatever you would like it to be' area. As I have 6 different title that I want to display <div class="image-slide-title">
St. Stephens
</div>

Comment: @PritiRathod bruh just replace `whatever you would like it to be` with your actual data, or any string stored in a variable

Answer (score 0):

If in the div there is only a text:

```
$('.image-slide-title').html("<h1>" + $('.image-slide-title').text() + "</h1>");
```

Comment: Question to your solution: how will this look in Vanilla JS ? Because I think using jquery for this functionality only could be a bit much or am I wrong there ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet,

```js
var  container = document.querySelector('.image-slide-title');
var title = '<h1>'+container.innerHTML+'</h1>';
container.innerHTML = title;
```

```html
<div class="image-slide-title">
St. Stephens
</div>
```

Comment: Squarespace just give access to inject code either in header or footer. Can I inject this code in either of it?