# add h1 tag in a div which is used and created in a js file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am using [this Cookie-Consent](https://github.com/brainsum/cookieconsent) from github and i have the following problem:

The banner (ccb__wrapper) contains text and the buttons but i need there also a title (h1) before the Text.
Is it possible to insert the  tag in the cookie-consent without touching the JS-file using HTML, CSS, PHP or JS?

I tried the Solution from here

[How can I write a script which help me to add H1 tag in between Div tag in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58621321/how-can-i-write-a-script-which-help-me-to-add-h1-tag-in-between-div-tag-in-html)

```
    const myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('ccb__wrapper')[0];
    let title = document.createElement('h1');
    title.innerHTML = 'whatever you would like it to be';
    myDiv.appendChild(title);
```

with different div's but it did not work.

Update:

After looking at Sikandar Mustafa's answer, and following his thoughts, it's shown where it should.

This is the working Code:

```
window.onload = () => {
    const myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('ccb__wrapper')[0];
    let title = document.createElement('h2');
    title.innerHTML = 'whatever you would like it to be';
    myDiv.prepend(title);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work", did you get an error, did it show up in the wrong place?

Comment: Can you describe what "did not work"? Please describe your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the ccb_wrapper class element is not yet rendered, JS function works asynchronously you should add this logic somehow after the completion of the above function and you also can try preappend function.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I forgot the "window.onload = () => {" before the script and i needed "prepend(title)" instead of "appendChild(title)"

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering whether or not you actually need to add a new element. You can create similar effects by giving the h1 tag a class. Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .pink {
                background-color: pink;
            }
            .hello {
                display: none;
            }
            .hello.speak {
                display: contents;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="pink">
            <h1 class="hello">Hello</h1>
            <h1>Push the button</h1>
            <p></p>
            <button onclick="hello()">Add</button>
            <button onclick="remHello()">Remove</button>
            <script>
                function hello() {
                    document.querySelector('.hello').classList.add('speak');
                }
                function remHello() {
                    document.querySelector('.hello').classList.remove('speak');
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course, you can have other events adding this classlist, if you wish. Be sure to have a counteracting event to remove the classlist. I have found this an easy way to remove text. You can remove divs this way too, so you can remove large pieces of the website, if you wish. I have used this method before and it has proven an easy solution.